# The named parameter 'color' isn't defined for ElevatedButton

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, dart

the color is not recognize by the VScode(flutter)

The named parameter 'color' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'color'.dartundefined_

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3rCl.png)

I tried a lot of searching and doing all things from my end like cleaning and restarting.

Answer (score 1):

`ElevatedButton` has no color property.

This widget has the following properties for color control:

- `backgroundColor`,
- `foregroundColor`,
- `overlayColor`,
- `shadowColor`,
- `surfaceTintColor`.

To configure them, add the property: `style: ButtonStyle(...)`,

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation of `ElevatedButton`.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html)

It has no *color* attribute.

As you're working on Visual Studio, you can always hover on the class name and it will give a list of all the attributes of that widget.